# ¿Cómo mostrar un texto en un mat table dependiendo lo que te regrese un servicio en Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

Tengo la siguiente tabla que se llena con un servicio, en donde el campo **clave seguridad** me regresa valores como "INP, ERR, INF" y lo que yo quiero pintar en ese campo de la  tabla es "In Progress, Error, Informativo" es decir, como la descripción de la clave

Como puedo hacer para pintar esa descripcion, cómo evalúo, si cveSeguridad = INP , pinta In Progress en la celda cveSeguridad

este es mi html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

                <ng-container matColumnDef="evento">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> EVENTO </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.evento}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="estado">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> CLAVE ESTADO </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"
                        [ngClass]="{'text-red':element.estado== 'Error', 'text-green':element.estado== 'En Ejecución'}">
                        {{element.estado}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="cveSeguridad">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> CLAVE SEGURIDAD </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.cveSeguridad}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="fechaEvento">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> FECHA DEL EVENTO </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.fechaEvento}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns">
                </tr>
                <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
           </table>
```

Component.ts

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['evento', 'estado', 'cveSeguridad', 'fechaEvento'];
            bitacora: Bitacora[] = [];
            @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

            constructor(private service: BitacoraService) { }

            ngOnInit(): void {
                this.obtenerDatos();
    
            }

            dataSource: any;
            obtenerDatos() {
                this.service.obtenerDatosBit().subscribe(response => {
                if (response.data.length == 0) {
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'error',
                        text: 'Sin datos para mostrar'
                    })
                } else {
                    this.bitacora = response.data;
                    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.bitacora);
                    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
                }

            });
            }
```

Comment: ¿Y por que no realizas una validación parecida que tienes en tu columna de clave estado en la otra columna?